# What would be the regex for this pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

My Java program, in certain point, receives a string containing a couple of key-value properties like this example:

```
param1=value Param2=values can have spaces PARAM3=values cant have equal characters
```

The parameters' name/key are composed by a single word (a-z, A-Z, _ and 0-9) and are followed by an `=` character (not separated by spaces) and it's value. The value is a text that can contain spaces and last until the end of the string or the begin of another parameter. (which is a word followed by equals and it's value, etc.)

I need to extract a `Properties` object (string-to-string map) from this string. I was trying to use regex to find each key-value set. The code is like this:

```
public static String createProperties(String str) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(some regex).match(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group();
        String param = ...; // What comes before '='
        String value = ...; // What comes after '='
        prop.setProperty(param, value);
    }

    return prop;
}
```

But the regex wrote is not working correctly.

```
String regex = "(\\w+=.*)+";
```

Since `.*` tells the regex to get "anything" it found, it will match the entire string. I want to tell the regex to search until it finds another `\\w=.*`. (word followed by equals and something after)

How could I write this regex? Or what would be another solution for the problem using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **Negative Lookahead** here.

```
(\\w+)=((?:(?!\\s*\\w+=).)*)
```

The key is placed inside capturing group `#1` and the value is in capturing group `#2`. Note that I used `\s` inside the lookaround in order to prevent the value from having trailing whitespace.

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aC1zP1/5)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I don't know to use negative lookahead, I will study to try to understand better the regex.

Answer (score 1):

One way among several:

```
List<String> paramNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> paramValues = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([^\\s=]+)=([^\\s=]+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        paramNames.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
        paramValues.add(regexMatcher.group(2));
    }
```

The regex:

```
([^\\s=]+)=([^\\s=]+)
```

The code retrieves keys as Group 1, values as Group 2.

**Explanation**

- `([^\\s=]+)` captures any chars that are not a whitespace or an equal to Group 1
- `=` matches the literal `=`
- `([^\\s=]+)` captures any chars that are not a whitespace or an equal to Group 2

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
(\\w+=(?:(?!\\w+=).)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rJ6gZ3/3)

It captures the `param=value` pair upto the next `param=`. It captures three `param=value` pair into three separate groups.

**Explanation:**

- `\\w+=` Matches one or more word characters followed by an `=` symbol.
- `(?:(?!\\w+=).)*` A non-capturing group and a negative lookahead is used to match any characters not of characters in this `\w+=` format. So it captures upto the next `param=`